# Windows 7 keep computer from idling

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, macros

I have to work on a corporate computer that has loads of security. I cannot install any programs. I am a software engineer and can write scripts/use command lines. I sometimes need to fix performance issues on software and need to trace them while they execute. These executions can sometimes take 30 minutes - 1 hour. The Windows 7 auto-locks after like 10 minutes, so I have to sit there and make sure to move the mouse/press a button so it doesn't idle and mess up my trace. In Power Options I have everything set to do nothing, but somehow it's all overridden and those settings don't mean anything.

Does anyone have any tips on how to make the computer not idle? like a windows 7 terminal command or something to use in any microsoft office programs or anything?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't install anything, but can you run an executable that doesn't needs installing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a fundamental conflict between the job you were hired to do, and the tools you were provided to do the job.  Assuming you can't use that computer for something else productive while that trace is running (you probably can), you are either hired to do the mouse / keyboard manipulation for that period of time, or the computer support team (whoever set up the screen lock feature) is preventing you from doing your actual job which is somewhere afk (reading a manual / reference book?).  I strongly recommend you address the issue from that perspective first.

That said, if there are no actual repercussions for violating company security policy (and believe me, there often are and probably should be), you can work around the restrictions using hardware / software.  One tool is listed below.

https://www.wiebetech.com/products/MouseJiggler.php

Comment: «this is a fundamental conflict between the job you were hired to do, and the tools you were provided to do the job.» Oh yes! Totally agree with this. Too much "security" (paranoid mode) = unusable computer.

Comment: Agree. Too much security makes things unworkable. Too little and you can wait for a disaster. Sadly how much is needed is often chosen at a corporate level and you are not allowed to deviate from it. (Not even for sane reasons). Which is when user & local get their head togetter to work around these limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I know three ways.

Lets start with an amusing one:
You make sure the mouse moves regularly. Get a motorised baby cradle. Put mouse in cradle. Done (Yes, this actually got done in a place.)

Much more practical:
The police sometimes needs to seize computers and prevent them from going into possibly lock screensaver session. They have a small USB device which identifies itself as a normal mouse and occasionally sends some input.

And possibly the one to use:
Some Microsoft programs can disabled the screensaver while they run. I though window media player was one of them. If it already is installed then just start this.

Comment: If you're really into it, use a TeensyDuino and program it to make input once in a while.